# Missing Site Collection Feature Permission prevents custom web parts from being added to a page

Tags: custom-web-parts

I created a custom web part hello world and deployed it to a local SharePoint 2010 (Developer laptop) successfully.
However, when I try to add the web part to a page, it errors off. The error in the event viewer is this:

> An unexpected error has been encountered in this Web Part.  Error: A Web Part or Web Form Contrl on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. **You don't have Add and Customize Pages permissions required to perform this action**

I checked my permissions and I am a Site Collection Admin

I compared Site Collection Features with a co-worker and he has lots more features than I do
I am suspecting it is a permission problem but because the feature is not displaying, I can't activate it to allow.  How do I unhide (make visible) OR restore the features concerning adding custom web parts/pages? (I would like all the features that should be there on a default SharePoint Install.

Is there a list screen shots of the Site Collection Features that should be displayed somewhere at Microsoft web site?

Comment: I hope that this's not the case... but are you sure the SharePoint version is the same between your machine and your co-worker one?

Comment: Hi, is this error happen for every page or only one? Maybe this is really problem with page? Check ULS SharePoint logs also, often it provides more information then Windows Event Viewer logs.

Comment: This is happening on all pages.. This sharepoint 2010 Enterprise Edition is loaded on my Windows 7 Developer laptop.  I can add non-custom web parts but I can't add custom web parts to any page.  I am the site collection admin.  I went ahead and added the Add and Customize Pages perm level, created a group and added my self to it.. Still, I get the error. I am the site collection admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up flattening and reloading my laptop. Then installed SharePoint server 2010 and then Visual Studio 2012. This cleared-up the problem. I can now add a simple custom web page (hello world) to a SharePoint page on my laptop.  I had opened up an incident with Microsoft but several days had gone by (gave them logs and config settings -but they hadn't identified a fix).. TO save time, I went ahead and took a drastic measure (e.g. installing OS, installing Sharepoint and then installing Visual Studio 2012 to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the SharePoint install on the Laptop didn't finalize the configuration. Try running the SharePoint Production Configuration. I had a similar issue once, and most of my features and service applications weren't setup successfully. I re-ran the Production Configuration and that Fixed my issue.

Comment: when you say rerun production configuration, what exact command are you talking about???

Comment: From Start Menu-> Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products -> SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration